# Bowled after scoring a run

Tags: rules, cricket

Today my colleague, a batsman hit a shot, a top edge which went high up, the wicket keeper and the bowler came for the catch, the batsman sneaked in a run, in the mean while both failed to catch the ball and the ball dropped in and since it a top edge, started to roll back in the direction of the stumps and ultimately hit the stumps.

We contended that the ball was dead once the run was completed, the bowling team countered that the ball had hit the stumps hence the batsman was out.

Is he out? what happens to the run completed?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the ball knocked one or more bails off, then provided no-one on the fielding side touched the ball before it hit the stumps, the batsman would be out Bowled under [Law 30.1](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-30-bowled/) parts (a) and (b):

> The striker is out Bowled if his wicket is put down by a ball delivered by the bowler, not being a No ball, even if it first touches his bat or person [...] he shall not be out Bowled if before striking the wicket the ball has been in contact with any other player or an umpire.

Under [Law 18.9](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/), no runs would be scored:

> When a batsman is dismissed, any runs for penalties awarded to either side shall stand. No other runs shall be credited to the batting side, except [under certain circumstances not relevant to the current scenario]

For reference, the completion of a run does not make the ball dead. None of the events in [Law 23.1(a)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-23-dead-ball/) had occurred, and neither had both sides "ceased to regard it as in play", as stated by Law 23.1(b).